# Kivy scatter on desktop with size=Window.size

Tags: kivy

I am developing an application for Linux desktop using Kivy framework. I am trying to set Scatter size the same as the size of the window.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle


class MyScatter(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyScatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.size_hint=(None, None)
        self.size=(Window.width, Window.height)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(100, 200))

class ScatterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScatter()


ScatterApp().run()
```

When I run the code the scatter immediately reflects my mouse motion and moves rectangle.
When I maximize window it reacts agter I press the button only but also scales and rotates itself as if I used two fingers.

When I use a fixed size (i.e. `self.size=(100, 200)`) the behavior is identical in both cases and scatter moves after I press the button.

Passing the size as a parameter doesn't change anything.

I don't use kv language.

"Mouse" is touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your mouse problems, but the `MyScatter` widget will fill the window by default. Your code doesn't reflect the correct size. Try this version:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyScatter(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyScatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.show_size, 0.1)

    def show_size(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)


class ScatterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScatter()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ScatterApp().run()
```